# MediaElement randomly stops playing audio from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, silverlight

In my Silverlight application, I read audio data from a File with a ZipInputStream, then store it in a MemoryStream. Here's the code I'm using:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
int len;
while ((len = zipInputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    memoryStream.Write(buf, 0, len);
}

// Reset the position for reading.
memoryStream.Position = 0;
// Check how large the byte[] is.
textBox.Text = memoryStream.ToArray().Length.ToString();    

MediaElement me = new MediaElement();
me.setSource(memoryStream);
me.Play();
```

This code partly works; the song from the input file starts playing. In addition, the byte[] always has the same length for the same song. I take this to mean that the song is being completely read each time.

However, my problem is that the audio randomly stops playing at a different point each run through. The song has not yet fully played, either. I'm not exactly sure why this happens.

If anyone knows, I'd like to know why this is happening. I'd also like to know if there's something wrong with my code, or if there's a different way I should go about storing the audio (that doesn't involve storing a file on the user's computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution. By making the MediaElement and MemoryStream global variables, the song played through completely each time. I'm still not 100% sure what caused this error, although my best guess is that the problem was caused by the garbage collector deleting the stream.